# 90s (or earlier) British TV show about school boy who discovers alien ship

Tags: story-identification, tv

TV show I saw in the 90s, I think it was British.

Main character is a high school boy who discovers an alien spaceship while out walking with a friend. They keep the ship hidden and fight over how/if to use it.

I remember a specific scene where someone discovers their secret and the boys panic and chase after him in the ship. After flying for a bit the camera switches to a cockpit view and you can see the man hurriedly walking up a hill towards the school on the main display while the boys frantically try to figure out what to do. They decide to fire a stun ray but realize too late that it was calibrated for a much larger radius than planned (10km vs 10m) and end up knocking out the entire school in addition to the fleeing man.

Ship was relatively small, about the size of a car, and bronze colored. Was bulbous in design; not many hard lines and kinda tapered on one end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Aquila* (1997).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0201376/):

> Geoff and Tom are best friends but very different. Geoff is sporty and adventurous. Tom is cautious and a bit of a worrier. So when they make the most amazing discovery, they deal with it in very different ways. The boys are on holiday in Wales when **they find - hidden beneath the body of a Roman centurion in a cave - a flying machine!** The cave soon becomes a major archaeological site, but the boys tell no-one about the machine. Back home, **the boys keep the machine, Aquila, in the garage, telling their parents it is an old prop left over from a film set**. Aquila has a marvellous invisibility switch. Not only can they have all kinds of bizarre and hilarious adventures in Aquila, they can have them unseen.

The episode you're remembering is series 2, episode 2, "Battling Bobby". [Its IMDb summary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1065568/) says it all:

> New boy at school, Bobby, picks fights with everyone. Tom and Geoff decide to use Aquila to prevent Bobby from fighting, but a miscalculation leaves the entire school unconscious.

But for the sake of completeness, here's the scene on YouTube. The stun ray starts around 9 minutes in.

---

Found with the Google query `british science fiction tv show boy "find * alien ship" alien`.

Comment: It says something about the kind of child I was that my main memory of this show was the fact the spacecraft used Latin (since it had last been calibrated for its Roman occupant).